# SIGINT signal unable to terminate java process with loop

Tags: java, loops, process, kill, sigint

`kill -SIGINT <pid>` is not killing my java process with a given specific code. Neither the Ctrl+C is working. 
I have the following java code.

CODE1:

```
class LoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("---start---");
        countPrimes();
        System.out.println("---end---");
    }

    public static void countPrimes() {

        for (int i = 2; i < 10000000 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < i ; j++) {

                    int x = i % j;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java process with the above code is running for long and if I kill this java process through command

```
kill -SIGINT <pid>
```

The process could not be killed.

But if run the following code with the infinite loop as

CODE2:

```
class LoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("---start---");
        countPrimes();
        System.out.println("---end---");
    }

    public static void countPrimes() {
        for (int i = 2; true ; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < i ; j++) {
                    int x = i % j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR if I run this simple code

CODE3:

```
class LoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("---start---");
        countPrimes();
        System.out.println("---end---");
    }

    public static void countPrimes() {
        while(true){}
    }
}
```

For both of the above CODE2 and CODE3, I can able to kill the java process with the command `kill -SIGINT <pid>`. What is wrong with the CODE1 ? OR Why the java process running CODE1 cannot be killed with SIGINT signal?

Please note: I can able to kill all the process with command `kill -SIGKILL <pid>` . But my question is specific to the **SIGINT** signal.

Comment: what is the infinite loop in your first code? also: what are you asking about? SIGINT and SIGKILL or Java code?

Comment: @Stultuske please read question after the edit. My question is there something wrong with java code1? That the process could not be killed with SIGINT kill signal.

Comment: @Aayush Jain what is the purpose of doing this  ?

Comment: @SahilAggarwalI have wrote a piece of code which was taking too long to complete for a given value of a variable ( > 10000000 in my case). And i was executing this piece of java code inside docker with the given timeout. So, after a timeout, I have to kill the process. But then I get to know that I cannot kill it with SIGINT. I know that SIGINT is not a good approach to kill a process as it interrupts the stream. But now I am just curious why this particular code can't be get killed but the other one can be. Either there is something with the code or sigint concept?